# lua serialize and unserialize a table that has function value

Tags: lua

Hi I had a table looks like this

```lua
local tbl = { AAA = {'ssss',require('xx').func_name}, BBB = {'aaa','bbb'}}
```

Now I can serialize this tbl use this function.

```lua
local function serialize(obj)
  local text = ""
  local t = type(obj)
  if t == "string" then
    text = text .. string.format("%q", obj)
  elseif t == "function" then
    text = text .. 'load('..string.dump(obj) ..')'
  elseif t == "table" then
    text = text .. "{\n"
    for k, v in pairs(obj) do
    text = text .. "[" .. serialize(k) .. "]=" .. serialize(v) .. ",\n"
    end
    text = text .. "}"
  elseif t == "nil" then
      return nil
  else
      error("can not serialize a " .. t .. " type.")
  end
  return text
end
```

but how can I unserialize this tbl? I don't know how to restore this function

Comment: Try`'load('..serialize(string.dump(obj))..')'`